# Android Dealing with click events

Tags: java, android, events

I have two questions, if you have extended a view such that you new view is MyView extends View, and MyView has custom methods and variables, how do you access those methods and variables on onClick?

If

```
MyView mv = new MyView()
mv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // CANNOT access MyView since v is a View and not MyView?

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple.

```
mv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Just check whether the view is of your type or not.
    // If you are sure its gonna be MyView you can skip it
    if( v instanceof MyView) {
       MyView mv = (MyView)v;
       mv.yourCustomMethod();
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You precise the final keyword and then you'll be able to call method on mv.

```
final MyView mv = new MyView()
mv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mv.myFunction();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You could cast the input View (which is not my favorite option) to
   your MyView class.
2. You could make the MyView mv variable final and access it within your anonymous inner class.
3. Or You could break your OnClockListener out of an anonymous inner class to a
   nested class and setup MyView as a parameter

Example:

```
MyView mv = new MyView();
MyOnClickListener listener = new MyOnClickListener(mv);
mv.setOnClickListener(listener);

...

public class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    private MyView mv;

    public MyOnClickListener(MyView mv){
        this.mv = mv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mv.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I swear I tried that but I must not have. That's what I get for programming with a head cold.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `super` in this way:

`super.myParentMethod()`

The parent methods and variables/accessor methods must be at least `protected` to access them.  They cannot be `private`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `View v` to `MyView` in order to call your own methods.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MyView mv = (MyView)v;
    mv.myMethod();
}
```